# Verifying binary patterns for large integers (BigInteger)

Tags: c#, .net, binary, numbers, bit-manipulation

I want to test a positive integer to see if its binary representation starts with zero or more 1's followed by one or more 0's.

```
00000000 // Valid
10000000 // Valid
11000000 // Valid
11100000 // Valid
11110000 // Valid
11111100 // Valid
11111110 // Valid
11111110 // Valid
11111111 // Not Valid
// Any other combination is Not Valid
```

The same expressed as a regular expression would be ^[1]*[0]+$. Of course this is only for clarification and we cannot use regex.

The brute force approaches:

- Create multiple bit masks, AND together to determine result.
- Loop through each digit with a dynamic mask to determine result.

The problem is that I am dealing with HUGE positive integers that can have hundreds of thousands of digits and need to perform this test for thousands of such numbers.

Is there a more efficient way to determine this binary pattern?

**UPDATE**

Here is the implementation I tried. Have not compared the time against other answers as yet.

```
public static bool IsDiagonalToPowerOfTwo (this System.Numerics.BigInteger number)
{
    byte [] bytes = null;
    bool moreOnesPossible = true;

    if (number == 0) // 00000000
    {
        return (true); // All bits are zero.
    }
    else
    {
        bytes = number.ToByteArray();

        if ((bytes [bytes.Length - 1] & 1) == 1)
        {
            return (false);
        }
        else
        {
            for (byte b=0; b < bytes.Length; b++)
            {
                if (moreOnesPossible)
                {
                    if (bytes [b] == 255)
                    {
                        // Continue.
                    }
                    else if
                    (
                        ((bytes [b] & 128) == 128) // 10000000
                        || ((bytes [b] & 192) == 192) // 11000000
                        || ((bytes [b] & 224) == 224) // 11100000
                        || ((bytes [b] & 240) == 240) // 11110000
                        || ((bytes [b] & 248) == 248) // 11111000
                        || ((bytes [b] & 252) == 252) // 11111100
                        || ((bytes [b] & 254) == 254) // 11111110
                    )
                    {
                        moreOnesPossible = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return (false);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (bytes [b] > 0)
                    {
                        return (false);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return (true);
}
```

Comment: Are you actually using them *as integers*, or just as bit stores? Frankly, if those were the only valid sets, I'd be using a different representation, I.e. "number of ones, number of zeros". Of course, that doesn't work if you need to do arithmetic etc.

Comment: http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html

Comment: I don't know what is HUME big integers, how this is represented on .net? I suppose arrays of ubyte/uint/etc.... is this it? @MarcGravell already asked but, are you doing some arithmetic with this data or it is just a representation?

Comment: @devundef: My mistake. It is supposed to be HUGE/LARGE, not HUME.

Comment: @RaheelKhan ahhh, that's make sense :)  So, how are you storing this values in memory? arrays?

Comment: @devundef: Yes. I'm using the BigInteger class that can allow access to the number as a byte array.

Comment: Tip: don't use extension methods, every time you call the method a copy of the your huge integer is made on memory; Use 'ref' whenever possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supposing the integers are stored in binary, grouped into an array x[] of unsigned integers, you can do this:

```
Define UINT to be the unsigned integer type you are using for the grouped bits.
Define UMAX to be the maximum value of that type (all bits are on).

// Find first word that has a zero bit.
int i;
for (i = highest word in x; 0 <= i; --i)
    if (x[i] != UMAX)
        break;

// Return true if all bits in all of x[] are on.
if (i < 0)
    return true;

// Test whether word conforms to the ones-then-zeroes rule.
UINT y = x[i];
if (y + (y & -y))
    return false;

// Test whether all remaining words are zero.
for (; 0 <= i; --i)
    if (x[i])
        return false;

return true;
```

In `y + (y & -y)`, `y & -y` returns the lowest bit set in y. (Proof left as an exercise for the reader.) If all higher bits in y are on, adding that lowest bit causes the carry to propagate through all those bits, changing them to zeroes. If any of those higher bits are off, the carry stops, and the result is not zero. Otherwise, the result is zero.

Can you improve on the above? Suppose comparison and branching have higher cost than operations like AND. In that case, you could use a binary search to find a location in the array where the values change from all ones to all zeroes or to neither. Test the critical word identified as above, then AND together all higher values and test the result of that for all ones, then OR together all lower values and test the result of that for all zeroes.

That gives you a binary search followed by one load and one AND or OR for each word. It would be hard to improve on that.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give both approaches a try and revert back with how much improvement there is compared to left-to-right byte array masking with predefined masks of 128, 192, 224, 240, 252 & 254.

Comment: Very elegant: y + (y & -y). I Used in my answer.

Comment: Thanks. The BigInteger class exposes a ToByteArray function. Converting to an array of long/ulong, etc. would induce extra overhead. Is there any reason your function shouldn't work on byte arrays instead?

Comment: My answer is written in a size-independent way; it assumes an array of unsigned integers. Those integers can be 8-bit, 32-bit, or other sizes. Nonetheless, using a larger unit sizes, whatever is natural for the machine, will likely have better performance. Converting a byte array to a 32-bit or 64-bit integer array should not actually change any data or move any memory. It is just a semantic issue to be dealt with in the compiler, such as casting a pointer to the new type.

Comment: Correction: Converting a byte array to a larger array can cause issues. If the byte array is not aligned as required/desired for 32-bit operations (for example), then performing 32-bit operations on it may cause either alignment exceptions or poor performance, depending on the target system. It would not surprise me if the BigInteger class naturally uses aligned memory, since that would facilitate its work, but somebody or some documentation would have to assert that.

Comment: Adding to that, for this particular purpose, alignment issues can be worked around by performing individual tests on unaligned bytes at the start and end of the array and then using larger word operations on all the remaining elements in the middle.

Answer (score 1):

In the worst case, without having additional data about the input stored, you cannot do better than an O(*n*) algorithm - where *n* is the number of bits - since you need to examine every bit in the number.

If you can keep track of e.g. "rightmost 1" and "leftmost 0" during previous manipulations, you can instantly obtain the answer by checking whether these are indeed "10".

Otherwise, you're just going to have to effectively iterate through the bits to check if it's correct. Note that going through the digits from the left until you hit a 1, and then checking everything is 0 (with the appropriate corner cases) is O(*n*) whereas having the full list of O(*n*) possible values and checking whether it is equal any of those in a (presumably?) O(*n*) comparison is O(*n*^2) and therefore a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

divide your binary data into blocks of a fixed size ... 32 bit ... 64 bit -> treat them as unsigned integers

prepare two hashmaps containing all valid patterns, and the inverse patterns (beginning with '0', and ending with '1') ... again unsigned integers

now test if the left most block is contained in the inverse pattern hashmap ... if not -> pattern is invalid
now test if the right most (non-zero) block is contained in the normal pattern hashmap ... if not -> pattern is invalid

now test if all other blocks are equal to the all-bits-set pattern (that should be a comparison to an unsigned integer) ... if all are equal -> pattern is valid ... else ... pattern is invalid